# How can I create an initial utilization state for storage in anylogic?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, logistics

I need my logistic platform / storage to have an initial state when the simulation first runs. This state is when some percentage (%) of the platforms is already full of pallets, which would be our normal situation during production. When the models runs, I need my AGVs/vehicles to start moving these pallets away and supplying new ones.
I'm supplying an image of what is expected based on a common public model found in Anylogic Cloud called "Distribution Center".

Distribution Center's first second of runtime

[image]

I couldn't figure out how to do it yet.
I also couldn't savage this from other models since they use old blocks and they are much more complex, what puts this little piece of the code inside of a much bigger scheme of variables and functions (I can't have all of this at the moment, need something simpler)

Answer (score 1):

The way it's done in this model and what I do aswell is the following:

1. Use an enter block before the store block from the MHL
2. Generate agents and put them in the enter block

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        enter.take(new Pallet());
    }
   ```

or alternatively if you have a pallet population somewhere

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        Pallet pallet=add_pallets();
        enter.take(pallet);
    }
```

1. use a really high speed for the agent in the enter block, something like 1000000000 meters per second so you get the impression that they are all in the pallet rack in the beginning of the simulation

This is the simplest way that works and doesnr require too much coding